# C# OleDbDataAdapter. Date format when reading Excel file

Tags: c#, excel, oledbdataadapter

I have connection string with IMEX option (all types are converted to string):

```cs
strConnectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\"{0}\";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;\";", strFile);
```

I use followed code to read xslx file into DataTable

```cs
DataTable table = new DataTable(name);
string sql = "SELECT * FROM [" + name + "]";
OleDbDataAdapter SQLAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
OleDbCommand selectCMD = new OleDbCommand(sql, SQLConn);
SQLAdapter.SelectCommand = selectCMD;
SQLAdapter.Fill(table);
```

Program reads the same file on two computers.

When the program runs on the first computer, I get date like string "31.03.2021". When the program runs on the second computer, I get the date like string "3/31/2021".

I cannot get the same date format on both computers. I already tried to:

1. Change the language format in Windows settings.
2. Set

   ```
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
   ```
3. Set

   ```
    table.Locale = new CultureInfo("en-US");
   ```

Nothing helps

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any Solution. So I started to use a option *IMEX=0* instead of *IMEX=1*.
Date are read correctly as DateTime type.